puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream (Puma Server, Nginx, Ruby on Rails)
I'm currently facing an issue with Puma. It's not running due to a puma.sock failure. If anyone has experience with this, please help me. I'll provide the error message below.
"==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <== 2024/11/08 06:54:54 [error] 24916#24916: *32 connect() to unix:/var/www/tutot/code/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.247.202.47, server: resources.tutor.com, request: "GET /embed/8 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/tutor/code/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/embed/8", host: "resources.tutor.com"
I've tried restarting the Puma server, but it continues to fail due to the puma.sock issue. I'm unfamiliar with Puma and the puma.sock file, and I'm hoping to run the server without encountering this error.
